# How to create Report designer in Python

Tags: python, wxpython, report, desktop-application

How do I go about creating a report designer in Python as..

1. Standalone desktop application.
2. Integrated in a custom desktop application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Libraries to look at:

[ReportLab](http://www.reportlab.com/) (I personally use this)
but I think [PythonReports](http://pythonreports.sourceforge.net/) will suit your needs.

Both libraries have sample snippet codes to start with.

Comment: Good answer, I have updated it with links to the libraries you have mentioned. +1 for pythonreports as I had not heard of it.

Comment: Thanks @BurhanKhalid. its my first post i'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Thanx answer was very helpful. One more thing, could you please guide me how can I go about creating functionality like where the end user can modify the reports on the fly according to their preferences, like they do by integrating crystal reports in an application.

Comment: That you need to handle in your python code, process all the data, columns accordingly then pass to report generating program. Or if you follow template approach then what user modify save in a temp report template and pass this to report generating program. Keep your code a little dynamic so it can behave according conditions